# Custom layout extending 2columns-left.xml

Tags: magento2, layout, page-layouts

I'm trying to create a custom layout based on 2columns-left.xml. The layout was created correctly and I can select it from the Admin. This is what I did so far:

1. I created the `layouts.xml` file `THEME/Magento_Theme/layouts.xml`

   ```
   <layout id="customlayout">
       <label translate="true">Custom Layout</label>
   </layout>
   ```
2. And then I created the `customlayout.xml` file `THEME/Magento_Theme/page_layout/customlayout.xml`
   With the same content as:
   `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/page_layout/2columns-left.xml`

The problem is that the layout has only 1 column, instead of 2columns-left, why?

Comment: Did you ever figure out this issue? I am having the same problem and aren't really finding any good documentation on how to achieve this. Hopefully nobody down votes this as I do not have enough reputation to comment... Thanks

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/145046)